# Parse the string

Tags: java, unix

Can any one suggest how to parse the the below string?

```
Added Active10000000044: {activityId=Active1, schedule=1 22 * * 0, isEnabled=Y, type=global, runAtHost=null}
```

I want `Active10000000044` part out to use further next step..

Comment: @Masud: It's clearly *not* JSON.

Comment: Is this full line a string?? **Added Active10000000044: {activityId=Active1, schedule=1 22 * * 0, isEnabled=Y, type=global, runAtHost=null}:**

Comment: Have you tried methods like String.substring() and String.indexOf()?

Comment: Have you tried Regex?

Comment: You can do this so many ways. You can use linux commands like 'cut' or you can user 'regex' or you can use java String.split() method or you can use open that file in notepad and copy paste.

Comment: @swa Try for an answer and select a one as correct one , it will good for next readers to get an idea directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the right of the ":" then you can use

```
String str = "Added Active10000000044: {activityId=Active1, schedule=1 22 * * 0, isEnabled=Y, type=global, runAtHost=null}:";

System.out.println(str.split(":")[1]);
```

The left can be found using

```
System.out.println(str.split(":")[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It *could* be as simple as:

```
String str = str.replaceFirst("Added ","").replaceFirst(" .*","");
```

depending on whether you've given us the full suite of test data :-)

If you want the second word regardless of the first, you could try:

```
String str = str.replaceFirst("[^ ]+ +","").replaceFirst(" .*","");
```

Both those suggestions rely on the fact that the first word is not preceded by spaces and that the white space *is* actually spaces. Any deviation from that will require some slight tweaks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
String str = "Added Active10000000044: {activityId=Active1, schedule=1 22 * * 0, isEnabled=Y, type=global, runAtHost=null}:";

String[] parts = str.split(":");

String part1 = parts[0]; // value "Added Active10000000044"

String[] SetU_need = part1.split(" ");

String u_need = SetU_need[1]; // value "Active10000000044"
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

[Splitter](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) class is from Google guava library

```
    String text = "Added Active10000000044: {activityId=Active1, schedule=1 22 * * 0, isEnabled=Y, type=global, runAtHost=null}:";
    int indexOfOpenBrace = text.indexOf("{");
    int indexOfCloseBrace = text.indexOf("}");
    String valuesAsText = text.substring(indexOfOpenBrace+1, indexOfCloseBrace);
    List<String> splitToList = Splitter.on(",").omitEmptyStrings().splitToList(valuesAsText);
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (String keyValues : splitToList) {
        List<String> splitToKeyAndValues = Splitter.on("=").omitEmptyStrings().splitToList(keyValues);
        map.put(splitToKeyAndValues.get(0), splitToKeyAndValues.get(1));
    }
    Set<String> keySet = map.keySet();
    for (String key : keySet) {
        System.out.println(key+":"+map.get(key));
    }
```

**Output**

```
activityId:Active1
schedule:1 22 * * 0
type:global
runAtHost:null
isEnabled:Y
```